# Mozilla plugin with xmlrpc server

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xml-rpc

I have been having this problem for hours, so i am going to post it and hope someone can give me some hints.

I am doing a Mozilla plugin and it requires to talk with the back-end server. The server is implemented as xmlrpc server.

My plan is to create a xmlrpc client in the plugin (javascript), then calls the server, but the same origin policy becomes the main issue. I do not know if there are alternatives can achieve my goals, or i have the wrong design of doing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to use [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) which enables javascript to call servers on different domains. the caller specifies the name of a callback function in the method call, and the server wraps the json results in a function call.  this ensures that the client has a chance to handle the return data.  also see [jquery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for an easy way to issue the request.

Comment: Thanks, i had looked jsonp already. The problem is that the server side need to be kept unchanged.